# Number of columns in a DataGridView

Tags: .net, datagridview

I must be missing something *very* obvious, since even searching for a couple of minutes returned nothing, but how can I get the number of columns in a `DatagridView`? The obvious `DataGridView1.Columns.Count` is wrong.

I am sorry if this has been asked a million times or has an obvious answer, but I just can't find it.

**Edit:** I just found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.aspx that the `DataGridViewColumnCollection` does have a property `Count`, so I used it and it worked. However, Intellisense does not suggest it. I had to manually enter it. Strange.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [`ColumnCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columncount.aspx)?

Comment: from MSDN: `ColumnCount - Gets or sets the number of columns *displayed* in the DataGridView.` I need the number of all columns, displayed and hidden.

Comment: @baruch How do you know there are hidden columns? If the number you get is wrong, how do you know what the right number is?

Comment: I am running it with my own custom data and I know the correct number. By a user this number may be different. I didn't test this function to see if it gives the right number. I just assumed the documentation was right.